# How do I tell ANTLR4 parser in C# what to do on parser errors?

Tags: c#, antlr4

I'm using ANTLR4, C#-Target to perfrom validity checks on data structures.
Basically, I have created an EBNF grammar describing the allowed sequence of occurences in certain elements.
The file itself does contain a lot of elements, and I'm using ANTLR to check every element on a single operation (they are different, independet and distinct elements, so I can not feasibily parse the whole file).
Typically, I could have a file containing about 5000 elements, about 1000 of them are invalid.

The extraction of the single elements from the file takes only about half a second with ANTLR on my machine, but when I try to check each of the elements I get a lot of NoViableAltExceptions or RecognitionException being thrown from the generated parser and they cause a huge drop in performance. A file without any invalid objects can be parsed in under one second, but when I have about 1000 errors it may take up to a minute.

Basically, I just want ANTLR to tell me if the input matches a given rule, if not, I want ANTLR to just report the error, abort the parsing process (since I just want a true or false answer) and NOT throw an exception.

I've tinkered with overriding / inheritance from the BaseErrorListener, the DefaultErrorStrategy and the Parser itself, and was somewhat able to change the behaviour of the generated parser, but I have one problem left:

The automatically generated file itself gets the line:

```csharp
                default:
                    throw new NoViableAltException(this);
```

Is there any way of telling ANTLR4 how to handle errors in the auto generated code, since this cannot be taken care of with overriding a framework class?

Thanks!

Comment: There are multiple ways to control the way errors are handled, but it's not clear from this question exactly how *you* want errors to be handled. I might be able to suggest a solution if you add that information.

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for the reply. Ideally, the parser would just stop parsing as soon as it has encountered an error. I need the parser only to tell me if it has encountered a rule (and then which subrule of it) or not. Is this possible with the parser?

Comment: Can you file an issue for this? Otherwise I'll probably forget to come back and answer this. https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/issues

Comment: Yes, I will file an issue for this on github. To put it in simpler terms: I want to validate a given arrangement of items against an EBNF description.

Comment: As for now, I "solved" it by just relying on the lexer, that means, I will only generate a token stream for the input and specify my EBNF sequences as lexer rules. In the next step, I am then able to check if a token was found and then check for the tokens name. This does allow me to implement a true/false check, however I do not get any information when the result is negative. I know this is a very specific (and probably uncommon) use of ANTLR, but this workaround works right now for me. I will not post this as an answer since it's not a real solution to my original question.